# Why did network percentage in Task Manager drop when the factual usage went up?

Tags: windows-10, home-networking

I was downloading something on my computer and Task Manager (under the Processes Tab) showed the download as "100% network utilization" and a speed of exactly 124.0Mbps. Someone in the house called out that the internet was slow, so i went to explain what i was downloading and they went outside (no longer using internet). After i came back i noticed that these statistics had changed to 32% and fluctuating around 308Mbps. I understand that a process can get a faster speed, but i don't understand why the "Network Utilization Percentage" lowers when the speed rises...
I have a 1Gbps Ethernet to my 1Gbps switch (Shared with a running desktop) that goes directly to the router.

[Image showing where i found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9nnL.png)

I tried to find a answer myself, but could only really find questions from people using a virtual machine, which i don't (As far as i know) have.
So my question is: **Why did the Network Utilization percentage drop while my laptop started to use more bandwidth?**
If i have to guess, i would say that the bandwidth is shared over the devices and my laptop only got 124.0Mpbs. When the others logged off, the connection got faster up until it got bottlenecked by the server i was downloading from, so the percentage lowered. This would suggest that my laptop (and Task Manager) should know how much my router is willing to give my Laptop.

Comment: Was this downloading on WiFi or a wired connection?

Comment: I have a 1Gbps Ethernet to my 1Gbps switch (Shared with a running desktop) that goes directly to the router.

Comment: Fair enough, I could see WiFi speed fluctuating as devices connect and disconnect as  WiFi access points (at least used to) adjust their signalling rate and "line speed" depending on devices connected. Alternately it is possible you have a marginal Ethernet cable and it dropped back down to 100Mbps for some time, possibly due to local electromagnetic interference (your colleagues device?) and when you went back the line had renegotiated at 1Gbps... Hard to know for sure without seeing the [link speed](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-determine-wi-fi-and-ethernet-connection-speed-windows-10).

Comment: To be clear, would need to see the link speed both during a "slow down" as well as during "normal" operation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've looked at the download speed in Steam initially, rather than Task Manager. Steam will by default use **MB/s** (mega**bytes** per second) and you saw it downloading at 124 MB/s. That's 992 **Mbps** (mega**bits** per second), so almost 100% of your 1 Gbps connection.

Later you looked at the Task Manager, which uses **Mbps**, and saw 308 Mbps, which is almost 31% of your 1 Gbps connection.

Comment: No, no. Steam displayed about 36-39 during the entire process. It really was from Task Manager both of the times.